# Why are the images not showing in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Note: this question is no longer relevant. The site has been moved to a new host and the the code on the site no longer applies.

Thanks.

I am trying to help out a client. The site is almost ready to go, but there are a series of images that simply disappear in IE7.

The click on the Leadership tab and the whole block of content vanishes.

Here is the html for that section:

```
<div id="leadership-content" class="content">
    <p class="intro">Leadership for every company is important in the daily management and growth as a business matures. At Moving Simplified we feel that offering our employees career-oriented paths gives them a more sincere desire to provide outstanding customer service.  All employees have the option to "climb the ladder" to eventually own a franchise of their own.</p>

    <div class="profile">
    <h3>Eric M. Snider<img class="flt-right" src="_images/Eric_Snider_Logo_Photo.jpg" alt="Moving Simplified Founder &amp; CEO Eric Snider founded Moving Simplified in 2007 as a new alternative to Charlotte moving companies by offering a suite of moving services of Pack It, Move It, Clean It and Junk It under one brand!" width="225" height="232" /></h3>
    <h4>Founder / Chief Executive Officer</h4>          
    <p>Eric founded Moving Simplified in 2007 as a professional services company with a new concept to assist people during one of the most stressful times of their lives:  moving.  His vision was to build a new type of moving services company - a company that would include every service that a customer would need during their move.  Bringing it all together in one company offering is the key differentiating factor with Moving Simplified.  "We are changing the face and perception of the moving company stereotype one move at a time," says Snider.  "We do this everyday by holding ourselves to a higher standard of service, people skills and performance."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gray-line"></div>

    <div class="profile">
    <img class="flt-right" src="_images/Ben_Photo.jpg" alt="Moving Simplified Founder &amp; CEO Eric Snider founded Moving Simplified in 2007 as a new alternative to Charlotte moving companies by offering a suite of moving services of Pack It, Move It, Clean It and Junk It under one brand!" width="225" height="232" />
    <h3>Ben Simmons</h3>
    <h4>Crew Leader / Senior Manager</h4>
    <p>Ben joined Moving Simplified in 2009 as one of the first management team members.  Ben's entrepreneurial spirit and physical fitness background makes him an excellent team player and role model.  "We're working hard everyday to help change the perception and face of the moving business," says Simmons.  "It can only be accomplished through discipline, desire and performance."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gray-line"></div>

    <div class="profile">
    <img class="flt-right" src="_images/Tim_Photo.jpg" alt="Moving Simplified Founder &amp; CEO Eric Snider founded Moving Simplified in 2007 as a new alternative to Charlotte moving companies by offering a suite of moving services of Pack It, Move It, Clean It and Junk It under one brand!" width="225" height="232" />
    <h3>Timothy Browne</h3>
    <h4>Crew Leader / Senior Manager</h4>
    <p>Tim joined Moving Simplified in 2009 as a team leader and manager.  Tim has a professional service background that was a natural catapult into Moving Simplified.  "As a crew leader and senior manager, I have a responsibility to ensure that our customers are 100% satisfied with our moving team's presentation, ability and performance," says Browne.  "Our goal is to be the area's top moving services provider and we strive to deliver that top-tier level of service with every customer."
    </p>
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.profile            { width: 630px; padding-bottom: 20px; }
#mainContent .profile h3     { margin-top: 10px; }
#mainContent .profile p { float: left; width: 350px; }
.profile img        { float: right; }
.gray-line  { clear: both; }
```

It shows up fine in Safari and Firefox but in IE7 it is nowhere to be seen.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The demo website is different than the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images that don't show all in the same folder? Try renaming the folders to a name without an underscore _ at the start.
By the way, the images don't show in my Firefox nor IE8.